# datetime difference for this syntax(d/m/Y H:m:s)

Tags: php, mysql

### [Duplicate of [DateTime difference from two tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700549/datetime-difference-from-two-tables/1700665#1700665)]

Hi, I need to find the date time difference from 2 tables.

My date time type is `Varchar` and the format is`(d/m/Y H:m:s)`.

How to find the datetime difference from 2 tables.

Comment: Didn't you ask the same question yesterday? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700549/datetime-difference-from-two-tables/1700665#1700665

Comment: Saving dates as a varchar field, instead of a datetime field, makes everything slower and more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html).
Play around with, for example

```
SELECT (TIMEDIFF(
    STR_TO_DATE('01/02/2009 12:00:00', '%d/%m/%Y %T'), 
    STR_TO_DATE('01/01/2009 12:00:00', '%d/%m/%Y %T')
);
```